# Does Singular complex determine a topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

This question comes from thinking about the singular geometric realization adjunction $Sing \dashv |\cdot|$. I suspect that this adjunction is not monadic, so using the Monadicity theorem I tried to cook up two topological spaces with isomorphic singular complexes, but are not homeomorphic. However, I could not think of such a space! I feel like I am missing something. The closest I got was a torus and a Klein bottle have the same chain complex groups but different maps. So my question is, is it true that two spaces have isomorphic chain complexes iff they are homeomorphic?

Comment: In the examples you're looking at, you seem to be confusing the singular complex and some other complex (maybe cellular?).  Rather trivially, any two reasonable spaces (say, manifolds of positive dimension) will have isomorphic singular chain groups, since all the groups will be free abelian of rank $2^{\aleph_0}$.  (Of course, the maps will usually be very different.)

Comment: oops you are correct, I think I was thinking of cellular complex! Thanks for clearing this up. I think I also thought that the maps had to be the same for the complexes to be isomorphic but this is probably not true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The singular simplicial set of a space $X$ knows only about paths in $X$, which in general are not enough to determine the topology of $X$.  For instance, let $X=\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology and let $Y=\mathbb{Q}$ with the discrete topology.  Then the identity map $Y\to X$ induces an isomorphism of singular sets $Sing(Y)\to Sing(X)$ (and hence also an isomorphism of singular chain complexes), since every map from a simplex to either space is constant.  But $Y$ and $X$ are not homeomorphic.